# Python create Counter object from dictionary, include a sum of values against summarised keys

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, counter

I have a dictionary with {ID: (INITIALS, DATE, AREA)} like so:

```
>> mydict = {1: ('JN', '2012-06-13', 2),
             2: ('JN', '2012-06-13', 5),
             3: ('JN', '2012-06-14', 8),
             4: ('AM', '2012-06-13', 3),
             5: ('OV', '2012-06-14', 4)}
```

I have been able to summarise the values like this:

```
>> from collections import Counter
>> mycounter = Counter((val[0], val[1]) for val in mydict.values())
>> for (initials, date), count in mycounter.iteritems():
       print ', '.join(initials, date, str(count))

JN, 2012-06-13, 2
JN, 2012-06-14, 1
AM, 2012-06-13, 1
OV, 2012-06-14, 1
```

I would like to also include a sum of the AREA of the value in mydict resulting in this:

```
JN, 2012-06-13, 2, 7
JN, 2012-06-14, 1, 8
AM, 2012-06-13, 1, 3
OV, 2012-06-14, 1, 4
```

Thanks!

---

EDIT:  WORKING CODE (modified slightly from Ashwini's code):
I moved v[1] to join v[0] in a tuple so it would summarise based on the intials AND date (I didn't make that clear in my initial question, now edited to reflect that), then calculate the count and sum the areas. Martijn's code also worked but this solution requires one less import.

```
stats = {}
for k, v in mydict.items():
    d = stats.setdefault((v[0], v[1]), [0, 0])
    d[1] += v[-1]
    d[0] += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a normal dict here:

```
>>> dic = {}
for k, v in mydict.items():
    d = dic.setdefault(v[0], [v[1], 0, 0])
    d[2] += v[-1]
    d[1] += 1
...     
>>> dic
{'OV': ['2012-06-14', 1, 4],
 'JN': ['2012-06-13', 2, 7],
 'AM': ['2012-06-13', 1, 3]}
```

Loop through the dict to get the expected output:

```
>>> for k,v in dic.items():
    print k +',',", ".join([str(x) for x in v])
...     
OV, 2012-06-14, 1, 4
JN, 2012-06-13, 2, 7
AM, 2012-06-13, 1, 3
```

If orders matters then you can use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dic = OrderedDict()
>>> for k, v in mydict.items():
         d = dic.setdefault(v[0], [v[1], 0, 0])
         d[2] += v[-1]
         d[1] += 1

>>> for k,v in dic.items():
...         print k +',',", ".join([str(x) for x in v])
...     
JN, 2012-06-13, 2, 7
AM, 2012-06-13, 1, 3
OV, 2012-06-14, 1, 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the full `Counter` API here, may as well replace that with a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

stats = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])

for entry in mydict.values():
    counts = stats[tuple(entry[:2])]
    counts[0] += 1
    counts[1] += entry[-1]
```

then printing:

```
for (initials, date), (count, area) in stats.iteritems():
    print ', '.join((initials, date, str(count), str(area)))
```

which outputs:

```
OV, 2012-06-14, 1, 4
AM, 2012-06-13, 1, 3
JN, 2012-06-13, 2, 7
```